# How to switch routing protocol midway from aodv to olsr in ns3?

Tags: simulator, network-protocols, ns2, ns-3, switching

How to implement routing protocol switching under ns3? For example, during simulation, switch from aodv protocol to olsr protocol?

The ns-3 version is 3.36.1.

Comment: ns3 question are mostly asked at ns-3-users   https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users : So far 24,266 questions ... and the ns3 developers may answer .....

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you, I‘ve asked the question at ns-3-users. Your comment is very useful, thank you agin.